# How do I identify a compatible power adapter for my hard drive?

Tags: power-supply, cable

I just got this hard drive back but the cables have been lost. Getting the right USB cable is easy enough, but how can I be sure that I'm getting a power adapter that works with it? It says 12V/2A under it, but I'm more concerned about physical size compatibility with the receiver.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Caliper.
2. Some Radio Shack stores (at least here, where they're not actually *called* Radio Shack anymore) have a display where they hang a bunch of power adapter connectors for fit testing.

A lot of them are 5.5/2.1 though.

Comment: Radio Shack / Best buy / etc, of course. Thanks!